# Converting a function's parameter - signature from using an `std::function<T>` to a template parameter type

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17, constexpr

In my existing codebase, I have a non-template class and its constructor has the following declaration signature...

```
struct SomeStruct {
    double a_;
    double b_;
    SomeStruct(double a, double b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
}

class SomeClass {
private:
    SomeStruct fields_;
    size_t n_;
    std::function<double(double)> func_;
public:
    SomeClass(SomeStruct fields, size_t n, std::function<double(double)> func) :
      fields_{fields}, n_{n}, func_{func}
    {}
};
```

I was using it like this:

```
constexpr double funcA(double x) {
    return x;
}

constexpr double funcB(double x) {
    return x*x;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass a(SomeStruct{1.0, 5.0}, 1000, &funcA);
    SomeClass b(SomeStruct{3.5, 7.7}, 2000, &funcB);

    return 0;
}
```

And the above representation works just fine...

---

I'm in the process of refactoring my code and I want to template my class and I'm trying to allow the class and its member functions to be defined fully as constexpr...

The new signature of my classes ought to look like this:

```
template<typename Field>
struct SomeStruct {
    Field a_;
    Field b_;
    constexpr SomeStruct(Field a, Field b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
};

template<typename FieldType, typename ValueType, typename Func>
class SomeClass {
    SomeStruct<FieldType> fields_;
    size_t n_;
    // std::function<double(double)> func_; // No longer using `std::function` since I want this to be constexpr
    Func* func_; // would like to save a pointer to a function, functor, function object, or lambda instead...
   public:
    SomeClass(SomeStruct<FieldType> fields, size_t n, Func* func) :
      fields_{fields}, n_{n}, func_{func}
    {}
};
```

There are two issues or problems that I'm having here or struggling with...

The `ValueType` template argument should be a part of the `Func` template argument... And as a side note, all of the function pointers, functors, lambdas, etc. currently have the form of accepting a single parameter of type `T` and they are returning a value of type `T`.

The other issue which is the "more important" issue involves when I try to instantiate an object...

```
SomeClass<double, double, ?> a{ SomeStruct{ 3.0, 5.0 }, 1000, &funcA };
```

I'm getting confused about the syntax for the template arguments for the function pointers... along with being able to pass in a function as an object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not specifying the template parameters for the constructor, but instead provide a deduction guide like this:

```
template<typename FieldType, typename ValueType, typename Func>
SomeClass(SomeStruct<FieldType>, ValueType, Func*)
 -> SomeClass<FieldType, ValueType, Func>;
```

and then you can call the constructor like this:

```
SomeClass a{ SomeStruct{ 3.0, 5.0 }, 1000, &funcA };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GWgT5n).

Additionally, there's no reason to store the function as a pointer, you could just store it as an object. As pointed out in the comments, this has the advantage that you can now store stateful lambdas as well.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9ZDCPZ) of that.

Comment: And not forcing the function to be a pointer makes the class more useful and general. For example, it would then allow using lambdas which capture, as in `SomeClass a{ SomeStruct{3.0, 5.0}, 1000, [multiplier](double x) { return multiplier*x; }};`

Comment: @aschepler That's a very good point. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Now, that I'm able to "instantiate" an object in this way... I have a newer but related issue... It involves the use of one of this class's member functions that performs the calculations which will invoke the function pointer, function object, functor, lambda, etc... that is now generating a compiler error...

Comment: Should I create new question? Or Should I just edit this question and put it below the original post in it's new section?

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that would be a separate question.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I figured as much... yet due to the relevance of this class, I really didn't want to start a new thread...

Comment: Try and remove as much stuff as possible while keeping the issue you have, for the new question.

Comment: @cigien Here's a link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164213/how-to-properly-invoke-a-function-object-within-a-class-templates-member-functi