# How to properly invoke a function object within a class template's member function? Visual Studio Compiler Error C2440 is being generated

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++17, self-invoking-function

This is a follow up to this question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163732/converting-a-functions-parameter-signature-from-using-an-stdfunctiont-t#62163820)!

Now, that I'm able to instantiate the object. I'm now getting a Visual Studio C2440 Compiler Error...

---

In my original code before it was templated I had a set of member functions that worked on the `std::function<double(double)>` member object that looked like this:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    double a_;
    double b_;
    SomeStruct(double a, double b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
};

class SomeClass {
private:
    SomeStruct fields_;
    size_t n_;
    std::function<double(double)> func_;

public:
    SomeClass(SomeStruct fields, size_t n, std::function<double(double)> func) :
      fields_{fields}, n_{n}, func_{func}
    {}

    double evaluate() {
        auto distance = fields_.a_ - fields_.b_;  
        auto dx = distance / n_;
        return calculate(dx, fields_);
    }

private:
    double calculate(double dx, const SomeStruct& someStruct) {
        double result = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_; ++i) {
            auto dy = func_(someStruct.a_ + i * dx);
            auto area = dy * dx;
            result += area;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Now my class looks like this:

```
template<typename Field>
struct SomeStruct {
    Field a_;
    Field b_;
    constexpr SomeStruct(Field a, Field b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
};

template<typename FieldType, typename ValueType, typename Func>
class SomeClass {
private:
    SomeStruct<FieldType> fields_;
    size_t n_;
    Func func_; 

public:
    SomeClass(SomeStruct<FieldType> fields, size_t n, Func func) :
        fields_{fields}, n_{n}, func_{func}
    {}

    constexpr ValueType evaluate() {
        auto distance = fields_.a_ - fields_.b_;       
        auto dx = distance / n_;              
        return calculate(dx, fields_);
    }

private:
    constexpr ValueType calculate(ValueType dx, const SomeStruct<FieldType>& someStruct) {
        ValueType result = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_; ++i) {
            auto dy = func_(someStruct.a_ + i * dx);
            auto area = dy * dx;
            result += area;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename FieldType, typename ValueType, typename Func>
SomeClass(SomeStruct<FieldType>, ValueType, Func) ->
SomeClass<FieldType, ValueType, Func>;
```

I'm now trying to use the class as such:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T funcA(T x) {
    return x;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T funcB(T x) {
    return x*x;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass a{SomeStruct{1.0, 3.0}, 1000, &funcA<double>};
    // a.evaluate();

    SomeClass b{SomeStruct{3.5, 7.5}, 2000, &funcB<double>};
    // b.evaluate();
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting this Visual Studio error...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Computations, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\...\main.cpp(33): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Integrator<double,int,T (__cdecl *)(T)>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=double
1>        ]
1>c:\users\...\main.cpp(33): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>Done building project "Computations.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is being generated before I even call its public `evaluate()` function that will call its
private `calculate()` function...

I'm trying to resolve this compiler error, and I'm trying to make sure that I'm able to invoke the function object, function pointer, functor, lambda that is stored within this class properly...

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Did you see that it was a follow up to a previous question? I only added to that which is already there from the original post... I added the two member functions that are in use here, and how I'm trying to use the class with the updated version... I'm now getting a compiler error at this point.

Comment: So to be able to reproduce your error someone has to stitch together parts of code spread across two different questions, and do this in some unclear order? Don't you think it's much easier for someone to be able to reproduce the actual error and have a complete picture of what's happening if they're looking at a complete [mre] in front of them? The best way to get help is to make it as easy as possible for others to see your problem. If you're asking others to spend some of their time to help you, it's only fair to ask you to spend a little of your time editing together a complete question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated my post to include the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the declaration of data member `Func`:

```
Func* func_;
```

It declares `func_` to be of a *pointer* to the type deduced by a deduction guide:

```
template <typename FieldType, typename ValueType, typename Func>
SomeClass(SomeStruct<FieldType>, ValueType, Func)
    -> SomeClass<FieldType, ValueType, Func>;
```

By calling the constructor with an address of a function:

```
SomeClass a{SomeStruct{1.0, 3.0}, 1000, &funcA<double>};
```

`Func` is deduced as:

```
Func = double(*)(double)
```

Thus, `Func*` becomes a pointer to a function pointer:

```
Func* = double(**)(double)
```

and that cannot be initialized with `&funcA<double>`. Instead, use `Func` alone as the data member type.

---

> *I'm trying to make sure that I'm able to invoke the function object, function pointer, functor, lambda that is stored within this class properly*

Either use a concept for that or a static assert:

```
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Func&, FieldType&>, "Invalid callable");
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, there is a typo in my question that was overlooked. `Func` is being declared as just an object and not a pointer. I'll update my question to reflect that... but the same issues within the question still apply...

Comment: As for the concept that would be nice, but I don't have a C++20 compiler yet... Still only C++17.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Does using parens for `func`: `fields_{fields}, n_{n}, func_(func)` , work ?

Comment: I think I got it working, you can check back on the other Q&A...